# Fast way to find the first unused key in a SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, key, sorteddictionary

If I have a `SortedDictionary<int, object>`, what is the fastest way to find the lowest key that is not currently being used? Obviously, we could iterate a counter i from 0->`int.MaxValue` and escape if `!Keys.Contains(i)`, but that would be very slow unless we were lucky and the first spare key happened to be early on in the sequence of keys. Maybe even a different .NET class does this for us already?

Comment: Do you know anything about the likely population of your dictionary? How many keys are there likely to be?

Comment: Sure - in fact I'd be happy to go the clunky way I proposed, or indeed keep track of spare keys, as it's not very likely that I'll have huge dictionaries, but a smart way would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, If I understand you correctly, the keys can be anywhere from `0` to `int.MaxValue`. In that case, you have to find the first "hole" in the sequence of keys.

This should do the job efficiently:

```
public static int GetFirstUnusedKey<TValue>(SortedDictionary<int, TValue> dict)
{
    if (dict.Comparer != Comparer<int>.Default)
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported comparer");

    using (var enumerator = dict.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return 0;

        var nextKeyInSequence = enumerator.Current.Key + 1;

        if (nextKeyInSequence < 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The dictionary contains keys less than 0");

        if (nextKeyInSequence != 1)
            return 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var key = enumerator.Current.Key;
            if (key > nextKeyInSequence)
                return nextKeyInSequence;

            ++nextKeyInSequence;
        }

        return nextKeyInSequence;
    }
}
```

I added a couple of checks to ensure the preconditions are valid.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a binary search on the keys?

You can use ElementAt() method to identify the key value at an index. If the key value is greater than the index, then search in the left sub dictionary or choose the right and go on that way till you find the index at which you observe the first difference between index and the value at the index.

Comment: Nope. `ElementAt` will enumerate the dictionary at each call,  @DrKoch. This makes this solution more like O(n²). It would work if `SortedDictionary` implemented `IList<T>`.

Comment: Hmmm. Good point @Lucas, but maybe a binary search would help if we looked for keys starting with intmax/2, then going left and maybe then going right if the left-half was full?

Comment: @Rob the problem here is that the class `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` doesn't implement `IList<TKey>`, only `ICollection<TKey>` and is not indexed.

Comment: @DrKoch I could do that, but then I'd lose the benefit of using the dictionary. My application needs to a) Keep track of the objects with a key that doesn't change, and b) Be able to retrieve an object by its key **fast**. The key overflow problem is not likely to happen but needs to be taken care of, just in case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming any sort of performance trophy for this approach, but I think it goes someway towards achieving your aim:

```
var sd = new SortedDictionary<int, object>();

sd.Add(1, 1);
sd.Add(2, 1);
sd.Add(4, 1);
sd.Add(5, 1);

var e = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Except(sd.Keys).First();
```

e = 3 in this case, as intended. I would expect that there are better solutions, though.

Comment: Nice. I reckon that'd be pretty efficient.

Comment: I'm sure it would be fine for a small dictionary. How it would scale, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Do not search for a unused key starting at 0.

Instead iterate the **used** keys, starting at the lowest (they are sorted).

Either the first is >0 then 0 is your lowest unused.

or there is a gap between two keys, then lower+1 is what you searched for.

Comment: I guess this is the prose version of Lucas' answer ;)

Comment: Lol. DrKoch - sure but can still be problematic for large dictionaries that are nearly "full". What do databases do when a primary key overflows?

Comment: Well, if you do this often, you could maintain a variable 'LastGapFoundAtKey' and start there the next time.

Comment: Databases wouldn't use `SortedDictionary` in the first place ;) If your dictionary is nerly full, you should use a different data structure.

Comment: It won't happen often, so in fact most any way would work, but I was just wondering if there is a clever O(log n) or better way

Comment: @Lucas I know, but they will still have some sort of algorithm for reusing spare keys (one would hope!) - e.g. what if your primary key was 8- or 16-bit, in which case running out of keys would be a real possibility

Comment: @Rob you could try csprabala's solution on a copy of `dict.Keys.ToList()`. This is a O(log n) after a O(n) copy operation. I suppose it won't be faster than a single O(n) search but I may be wrong.